# BottomAppBar Floating action button notch/inset is not transparent

Tags: flutter

I've added a `BottomAppBar` to scaffold in a materialApp, and to that I've added a fab with a inset at the center. The code looks somewhat like this

```
Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: _buildBottomBar(context),
    ),
    floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Center(
        child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            size: 32.0,
        ),
        ),
        onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateEvent()),
        );
        },
    ),
)
```

And this is what I'm getting after rendering:

[image]

The notch is not transparent, and the content behind it is getting hidden.

Is there a way to fix this? Something I might have missed?

Comment: Is your "content behind" specified as the `body` parameter of the `Scaffold`?

Comment: Yes, body holds all the content which is basically a list view of images and text.

Comment: I'd suggest raising an issue instead. It seems to be a layout problem, has the body doesn't go behind the bottombar.

Comment: Ohh that sucks. Thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: @RémiRousselet turns out there is an open issue for this -> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17555

Comment: Looks like a solution is coming very soon: [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/25654](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/25654) scaffold is going to have extendBody property which solves the problem for all of us. Upvote the merge request so that it comes out quicker;)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You just need to be on the flutter channel: **master** and then add to Scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
   extendBody: true
);
```

and it should be transparent :)

Greets

Rebar

**UPDATE**:

You don't need to be on master channel. It's included everywhere :)

Comment: Yeah, waiting for it to drop to master, since people won't want to ship on master. My app(s) are already in production, so need a stable build of flutter. Its been in master for quite a while now though, so hoping next release has this.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is if you put your content in the `body` of `Scaffold` it won't overlap the size of your `AppBar`, `BottomAppBar`.

You can try using `Stack`, put your body as a first child, then put the `Scaffold`, change the `backgroundColor` as Transparent.

```
        @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Image.network(
                      "https://images.pexels.com/photos/255379/pexels-photo-255379.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350"),
                ),
                Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                    color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
                          onPressed: () => null,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.sms_failed),
                          onPressed: () => null,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  floatingActionButtonLocation:
                      FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
                  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        size: 32.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      /*
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateEvent()),
                    );*/
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
```

Comment: I don't recommend this way, but I just to know why it happens

Comment: Yeah, so I tried this, this requires the actual body to have a theme manually set, and the scrolling becomes an issue. I'll probably stick with the original for now and hope for a solution to it. Here's the already open Github issue for it: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17555

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve the desired behavior by also setting the *resizeToAvoidBottomInset* flag to false.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: IndexedStack(
            children: <Widget>[],
            index: _selectedTab,
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)
            ),
            child: BottomNavigationBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                elevation: 10,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[],
                currentIndex: _selectedTab,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
```

Edit: keep in mind that you may have to manually set the bottom insets by using *MediaQuery.of(context)*

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted solution, if you are using `SafeArea` as an immediate child to `Scaffold` then make sure you set the bottom property to false.

```
Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  ...
  child: SafeArea(
    bottom: false,   /* important */
    child: Container(
      child: // your app content
    ),
  ),
);
```

This enables the content to flow behind the `BottomNavigationBar`